# Creating a custom CSS class binding for Knockout that accepts arrays

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to modify the `class` binding shown on [this page](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/wiki/Bindings---class):

```
ko.bindingHandlers['class'] = {
    'update': function(element, valueAccessor) {
        if (element['__ko__previousClassValue__']) {
            ko.utils.toggleDomNodeCssClass(element, element['__ko__previousClassValue__'], false);
        }
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        ko.utils.toggleDomNodeCssClass(element, value, true);
        element['__ko__previousClassValue__'] = value;
    }
};
```

So, currently, mine is like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.cssClass = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var cssClass = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
            prevCssClass = element['__ko__previousClassValue__'];

        console.log("Previous:", prevCssClass);
        console.log("Current:", cssClass);

        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(prevCssClass) === '[object Array]') {
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(prevCssClass, function (classAccessor) {
                var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(classAccessor);
                ko.utils.toggleDomNodeCssClass(element, value, false);
            });
        } else if (prevCssClass) {
            ko.utils.toggleDomNodeCssClass(element, prevCssClass, false);
        }

        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(cssClass) === '[object Array]') {
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(cssClass, function (classAccessor) {
                var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(classAccessor);
                ko.utils.toggleDomNodeCssClass(element, value, true);
            });
        } else if (cssClass) {
            ko.utils.toggleDomNodeCssClass(element, cssClass, true);
        }

        element['__ko__previousClassValue__'] = cssClass;
    }
};
```

I [created a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kamranayub/3ahUA/) which you can play with. My question is, the first time you click 'Change' this works like a charm, but any time after that, the `prevCssClass` is incorrect **for the `multiple` observable array** (single works great)... it reflects the `cssClass` not what actually should be the previous value. Why? I cannot figure out why this is happening, everything seems alright to me.

The bad console output is:

```
Previous: undefined
Current: ["blue","small"]

Previous: ["blue"]
Current: ["blue"]

Previous: ["blue","big"]
Current: ["blue","big"]
```

The correct output should be:

```
Previous: undefined
Current: ["blue","small"]

Previous: ["blue","small"]
Current: ["blue"]

Previous: ["blue"]
Current: ["blue","big"]
```

I'm testing in Chrome.

### Update:

The answer is below. If you're interested, the gist for this new binding is here (all cleaned up):

https://gist.github.com/kamranayub/5224521

Comment: I'm very tired today, but it this the behavior you would expect? http://jsfiddle.net/3ahUA/3/

Comment: Yes! Can you explain what you did and why `concat` fixed everything? Then I'll mark it as an answer.

Comment: Sure, I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little javascript trick I picked up somewhere... maybe jQuery's source, I can't remember.

The key is creating a copy of the array. Using `.concat()` basically appending a null array forces Javascript to create a copy of the existing array.

```
if (Object.prototype.toString.call(prevCssClass) === '[object Array]') {
    prevCssClass = prevCssClass.concat();
```

This allows you to store a historical copy of the current array. And any modifications to the original object won't affect your "Cloned" array.

Comment: Ugh! That makes sense, would've taken me forever to figure that out. Thank you!

Comment: The way I usually make a copy of an array is to use `slice`: `copy = array.slice(0)`. `concat` seems simpler though. Thanks!